# Set colour of text in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a simple listview which has its values defined in two string arrays, and I'm looking to have the colour of the text in the listview change if it equals a certain value.

Here is what i've tried, which isn't working

```
///rest of oncreate above
var = new String[]{"Text", "Words", "Other"};
val = new String[]{"t", "w", "o"};
preparelist();
///rest of oncreate would go here...
}

private void preparelist(){
thelist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < var.length; i++) {
            map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map2.put("one", var[i]);
            map2.put("two", val[i]);
            thelist.add(map2);
        }


        try {
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, thelist, R.layout.row,
                    new String[] {"one", "two" }, new int[] {
                             R.id.one, R.id.two });

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.one);
if(t.equals("Words")){
t.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}
}
```

Basically in this example, I want everything in the list that equals "Words" to be changed to blue, as the if statement checks for, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom adapter class by extending SimpleAdapter class and re-implement the `getView()` method. Inside the `getView()`, put a condition for the text color.

A good example of extending the SimpleAdapter is [here](http://dustinbreese.blogspot.gr/2009/12/creating-listview-with-alternating.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a BaseaAdapter, then define in getView what you want

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return *YOUR ARRAY SIZE OR LENGHT*;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View inflate = View.inflate(CONTEXT, COM.EXAMPLE.R.layout.list, null); //Your XML layout, you can even create it programmatically
        TextView tv = (TextView)inflate.findViewById(COM.EXAMPLE.R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(YOURARRAY[arg0]);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

        return inflate;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

listviews should be used with Adapters, and you want to override the getView() method of your adapter.

You should have a look at this link which is I find a great tutorial on how listviews work :
[vogella-tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter)

Here is a sample of code that would work :

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"Text", "Words", "Other"}) {
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView resultTextView = (TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    resultTextView.setText(textToDisplay);

    if ("Words".equals(textToDisplay)){
        resultTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }else{
        resultTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    return resultTextView;
}});
```

Note that this code is fine for recycling views, but if you want to create your own TextView in the getView method, you should recycle it otherwise your listview will experience bad performances (check the tutorial for that).

Answer (score -3):

I believe you need to change your if statement a bit:

```
String tString = t.getText().toString());

if(tString == "Words"){
   t.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Comment: this is not how to compare strings in java, plus this is far from an actual answer to the question.